# Timezone incorrectly calculated in R when script run on different OS

Tags: r, macos, datetime, ubuntu, posixct

I have run the exact same R script on two different machines and have gotten different results. I don't understand why...

Consider this integer as seconds since `1990-01-01 00:00:00 GMT+10`

```
int <- 817779600
```

I need to convert this to a POSIXct object and to do so I run the following R script on a computer running "OSX 10.11.4":

```
> time <- as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(int, origin='1990-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                tz='GMT'), tz='Australia/Sydney')
> time
[1] "2015-12-01 01:00:00 AEDT"
> as.integer(time)
[1] 1448892000
```

Now if I run the exact same code on another computer running "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" I get a different result:

```
> time <- as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(int, origin='1990-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                tz='GMT'), tz='Australia/Sydney')
> time
[1] "2015-12-01 02:00:00 AEDT"
> as.integer(time)
[1] 1448895600
```

I know the first value to be correct. Any idea as to what may be causing the discrepancy? Running date in bash on both machines gives the same result. Also is anyone able to reproduce this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Datetime parsing in R uses the systems utilities, so differences across OSes are to be expected. If it's possible try converting directly to `POSIXct`.

Comment: Thanks @snaut, I guess it's not a huge problem and easily dealt with if you are prepared for it. I guess it's definitely something to keep in mind when trying to run code on a different OS. In this case I was executing a model that took several days to run but the results were all nonsense due to this issue.